# Count number of occurrences in category grouped by date

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, group-by, count

I have a list of data (~7000) lines that are marked by their week commencing dates. Each row of data has a certain category associated with it, I want to make a query or results table that takes each unique commencing week date and summarizes the counts for each category based on rows of data that have that week commencing date.

I have tried using a combination of access queries and excel modifications.

My current data looks something like:

```
Category    week
A               5/20/2019
B               5/20/2019
B               5/20/2019
C               5/20/2019
A               5/20/2019
A               5/13/2019
C               5/13/2019
C               5/13/2019
B               5/6/2019
A               5/6/2019
A               5/6/2019
```

I want something in the format of:

```
week              A      B      C
5/20/2019         2      2      1
5/13/2019         1      0      2
5/6/2019          2      1      0
```

whether its in multiple queries or whatever, I just need this data separated like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible method is using conditional aggregation, e.g.:

```
select 
    t.week,
    sum(iif(t.category = "A", 1, 0)) as A,
    sum(iif(t.category = "B", 1, 0)) as B,
    sum(iif(t.category = "C", 1, 0)) as C
from 
    YourTable t
group by
    t.week
```

If you wish to group multiple categories together to be listed as a single category, you can use an `in` expression in the test expressions for the `iif` statements:

```
select 
    t.week,
    sum(iif(t.category = "A", 1, 0)) as A,
    sum(iif(t.category = "B", 1, 0)) as B,
    sum(iif(t.category = "C", 1, 0)) as C,
    sum(iif(t.category in ("D","E","F"), 1, 0)) as D
from 
    YourTable t
group by
    t.week
```

Alternatively, you can use a crosstab query, e.g.:

```
transform count(*)
select t.week
from YourTable t
group by t.week
pivot t.category;
```

Change `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Follow up question, if I have certain categories where I want their sum to be counted as one (say D, E, F should all be counted under column D) how would I go about editing the query for that?

Comment: You're welcome - I have updated my answer above to demonstrate how this could work for grouping multiple categories.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Pivot table:

Create a Pivot Table selecting all data (including header)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best way, to my mind, due you have mentioned MS Access in your tags is to use built-in methods:

```sql
    TRANSFORM Count(tblMyTableName.week) AS [Count-week]
    SELECT tblMyTableName.week
    FROM tblMyTableName
    GROUP BY tblMyTableName.week
    PIVOT tblMyTableName.Category;
```

Where `tblMyTableName` is name of your table.